# what is wrong on delete the item list view?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I want when click on button in list view items ,this item is deleted.
list view codes like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand"   >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div data-target="#modal_result" data-toggle="modal" onclick="func_getData();" onmouseout="javascript:func_UN_highlight(this);" onmouseover="javascript: func_highlight(this);">
                    <p>نام کتاب :  <%#(Eval("name_book")) %></p>
                    <p>نویسنده : <%#(Eval("author_book")) %></p>
                    <div class="q">
                        <p>ویرایش : <%#(Eval("edition_book")) %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="q">

                        <p>قیمت : <%#(Eval("price_book")) %></p>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#(Eval("image")) %>'/>
                    <asp:Button ID="Bbtn_delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id_book") %>' CommandName="delete" CausesValidation="True" UseSubmitBehavior="False"  CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="حــذف" />
                     <asp:Button ID="btn_edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id_book") %>' CommandName="edit" CausesValidation="True"  UseSubmitBehavior="False" CssClass=" btn btn-warning" Text="ویرایش" />
                                          <br>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

and itemcommand event like this:

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        string idbook = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        T_bookBusiness bookBusiness = new T_bookBusiness();
        T_book book = new T_book();
        book.IdBook = long.Parse(idbook);
        bookBusiness.Delete(book);
        //پر کردن دوباره لیست ویو
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

Now when click on the Delete button Item is deleted but show this error :The ListView 'ListView1' raised event ItemDeleting which wasn't handled.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of CommandName="delete" use CommandName="delete_row" or anything other than "delete".
Same is applicable for "edit".